# Why is this function still potentially returning 0?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why is rand_numb returning a random number that can still be 0?

```
def check_rand(numb):
    if numb == 0:
        numb += 1
        return numb
    else:
        return numb

def random_row(board):
    rand_numb = randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
    check_rand(rand_numb)
    return rand_numb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
check_rand(rand_numb)
```

The function `check_rand()` is called, then its result is thrown away. Change it to:

```
rand_numb = check_rand(rand_numb)
```

Comment: @user3349491 Note that in your code, `1` is more likely to be the result than the other potentials, but perhaps that is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid needing that function by replacing:

```
rand_numb = randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
```

With:

```
rand_numb = randint(1, len(board[0]) - 1)
```

Which makes the smallest result of `randint`: `1`; rather than `0`.